# HTML SEO: “alt” text attribute for related photos

Tags: seo, html, alt-attribute

If I have a photo gallery where each photo in the gallery has a mini-feed of 'related photos', should the alt text of these related photos describe these related photos or should they describe the fact that they are something like "a link to a related photo"?

As the title states I am asking my question in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 3):

According to MOZ, alt text describes an image for bots and the visually impaired:

> If you can close your eyes, have someone read the alt text to you, and imagine a reasonably accurate version of the image, you're on the right track.
>
> [What is Alt Text?](https://moz.com/learn/seo/alt-text)

So your alt text should be reasonably consistent, and should always describe the image itself. No need to include info like "related image" in the alt text. Instead, use an `h-` element to introduce that section of the page to average users and visually impaired users alike.

Answer (score 2):

Alt attributes are for users, not search engines. If you're purposely writing alt attributes for search engines then you are providing non-natural alt attributes which, in turn, lowers user experience and sends bad signals to Google/Bing, search engines want content optimised for users, not search engines. Look after your users and the search engines will look after you.

> Good usage of the ALT attribute is composing the image ALT value that
>   consists of a short description that informs users the context of the
>   image. Sometimes describing less is often more and other times more is
>   more! Your descriptions should contain the elements of the image that
>   you want them to visualise, it is not for telling Google to rank THIS
>   because of this KEYWORD. Treat the ALT tag as a solution for partially
>   impaired, completely impaired or for users that have disabled images
>   in their browsers.